# Android db.update SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have a small problem with the method db.update. I need to change a string that corresponds to that received by the query. For example from the query I get the string "hello", if the change in "hello1" must change all the strings "hello".
In my Cursor I have `name_s = c.getString(3);`
And this is my update:

```
cv.put(Table1.ABC, Ecia.getText().toString());
db.update(Table1.TABLE_NAME, cv, Table1.ABC+ " = ?",  new String[] { name_s});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
String newval=Ecia.getText().toString();

String name_s = c.getString(3);

setMyField(name_s , newval);

public int setMyField(String currvalue , String newvalue)  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Table1.ABC, newvalue);
    // updating row
    return db.update(Table1.TABLE_NAME, values, Table1.ABC + " = ?",
            new String[] { currvalue });
}
```